# Obtain the interval of the thousandth of a number c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get from a number the interval where this number is.

For example my number is 10:
By tens: [1-100]

My number is 110:
By tens [101-200]

Comment: What about numbers 7 and 7101? Is this for all numbers?

Comment: Yes for all number with a max range.

Comment: It looks like you want a range of floor(n/100) *100 + 1 to floor(n/100)*100 + 100 .  And if you want ranges like 1-10 or 1-1000 you'd just substitute 100 with whatever power of 10 you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @Juharr !

```
double n = 150;
double test = Math.Floor(n / 100) * 100 + 1;
double test2 = Math.Floor(n / 100) * 100 + 100;
```